# Visual Studio 2019 node.js docker remote debug: breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, docker, debugging

I'm trying to attach remote debugger of Visual Studio 2019 to node.js app in docker container. What I do:

1. I have created example node.js/express project in Visual Studio using "Basic Node.js Express 4 Application" template.
2. I have created docker image with following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
ADD ./TestApp/ExpressTestApp/ /
ENTRYPOINT node --inspect="0.0.0.0" /app.js
```

3. I launch container with following command:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 9229:9229 test
```

4. The app works, pages open on address http://localhost:3000/, console output states that debugger is active:

```
Debugger listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9229/73b5b00d-a492-4842-81e5-d50c12e64ac9
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

5. In Visual Studio 2019, I click "Debug -> Attach to process...". In opened dialog I choose "Chrome devtools protocol websocket (no authentication)", enter ws://localhost:9229/73b5b00d-a492-4842-81e5-d50c12e64ac9 as a connection target and I can see and connect to node.js debugger in docker:

[image: Attach to Process dialog]

6. I can successfully attach to the process (node.js output states "Debugger attached."). But I can't use breakpoints in source files. When I place brakepoint, it shows the message "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoint set but not yet bound."

**How to make it work in Visual Studio?**

I've tried to debug my app in VS Code, using following launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to remote",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "port": 9229,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/"
        }
    ]
}
```

And it works perfectly. Breakpoints, variables values watching and etc. And I don't need to specify generated GUID of debugger, which is great too.

**How to achieve the same thing in Visual Studio 2019?**